# Ubuntu Email Server identifies as Junk!

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot, static-ip

I set the Email server with `PostFIX` and `Dovecot`. But when I send emails from my server to `Gmail`, `Live` and other major Email services they put the email in the `Junk` or `SPAM` folder.

- What is wrong?
- What should I do to help the situation and prevent emails to identify
  as Junk?
- Is this related to my VPS `IP address`?

Comment: This [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/579780/184188) should help you

Comment: I don't remember exactly so i bet a few coins that it is related to lacking SPF record or DKIM signature.

Comment: @Anders F.  U.  Kiaer  could you explain what  you talking about.

Comment: http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/12/06/google-says-91-4-authenticated-non-spam-emails-sent-gmail-users-now-using-antiphishing-standards/#!yG8X4

Answer (score 0):

Can be related to you VPS ip address. You must have valid mx record and valid A and ptr record for VPS ip address.
Check with following commands

> host -t mx youdomain.com

You will get mx record from dns server

> host mail.yourdomain.com

after that

> host ip_address_of_vps

This is firs thing for chacking

Also you can check http://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php.
Maybe is your mail server on some blacklist.

Comment: So using `CloudFlare` could be one of the issues?

Comment: No CloudFlare, problem may persist with any mail server. Please check ip reputation, and validate dns records. This is first step.

Comment: The ip is not listed but still I get emails in junk

Comment: Check dns records